# Android WebView scroll down

Tags: android, scroll, webview

Is there a method or something to scroll de WebView at the bottom of the page..
I am using a WebView in a chat client as chatboard, and I want to scroll the page down as the user writes some text...

Thank you very much.

Comment: have u implemented chat application...?or you are using from web?

Comment: I have implemented the app.. I only use the webview for the messages

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At [Webview's reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#pageDown(boolean)).

> **`public boolean pageDown (boolean bottom)`**
>
> Since: API Level 1 Scroll the contents of the view down by half the page size.
>
> *Parameters*: **bottom** `true` to jump to bottom of page.
>
> *Returns* `true` if the page was scrolled

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void scrollToBottom(boolean animate) {
        if (animate) {
            pageDown(true);
        } else {
            scrollTo(getScrollX(), computeVerticalScrollRange());
        }
    }
```