# How to handle "infinite" web pages?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Once upon a time, life was simple: All web pages had finite length and if they didn't fit into the current windows/view size, you'd simply scroll down until you reached the bottom of the page.

But I recently noticed that there is a new trend in the web design world: **Bottomless** web pages.

Probably the most familiar examples of sites utilizing such pages are Facebook and Twitter: You scroll to the "bottom", only to trigger some refresh that adds content to the page, so the "old bottom" is no longer a bottom and, instead, there is a new "bottom".

In an Android WebView, I need to be able capture all the content currently available on that "page", but I am not sure how to approach this:

Simulate user's scroll down via [View.scrollBy(int x, int y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069765/android-webview-how-to-autoscroll-a-page/5070157#5070157), [pageDown()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680174/android-webview-scroll-down/4680975#4680975) or  [window.scrollTo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238938/how-to-programmatically-scroll-android-webview/2239301#2239301)?

Or is there an API method that does this automatically for me?

Or am I approaching this completely wrong and I shouldn't attempt to get to the "real bottom" in one capture (if possible at all)?

**EDIT**: It seems that tagging this question `javascript` communicated the opposite message. I am interested in capturing (then processing) such bottomless pages on Android's WebView, using **Java**.

Comment: I'm not clear what "all the content currently available on that page" means in this context. If the page is "bottomless", doesn't that imply that there's a potentially infinite amount of content on that page? Or are you just wanting to trigger a certain number of these "load more content" events and then capture that?

Comment: @Sean McMains Yes, I just want to trigger a certain number of these "load more content" events and then capture that. "Infinite" is only theoretical and/or figurative: A twitter (and Facebook) page can only go back so much in time.

Comment: But that is the point isn't it. You could go on for any amount of time. If you want to get data from these services then use twitters API's to get somebodies entire history. This is not even a good idea. I would cap of "going further back" with a date or a set number of items.

Comment: @Robert Massaioli You are correct of course if all I wanted is to do something very specific to Twitter. But I only brought Twitter & Facebook as examples. The number of such "bottomless" sites are spreading like a virus... :) I was hoping to start here a brainstorm session discussing creative approaches to handling this from the WebView side, but the only 2 answers I received so far, were for how to program such sites. +1 for the constructive criticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** disregard this answer, I misunderstood the question.  Leaving the answer in case others misunderstand the question as well.

---

You could use the [*jqPageFlow* jQuery plugin](http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/jquery-plugin-jqpageflow-scrolling-pagination-made-easy/), or base yourself on its documentation.

[Infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) is another great option.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to *capture* the content from an infinite-scroll page, not create one.

Comment: @zerocrates You are correct. Thanks and + 1 for communicating my intent better.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin does just that:
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

Another, with jQuery an PHP:
http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

Comment: Another: http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/create-a-dynamic-scrolling-content-box-using-ajax/

Comment: Do I understand correctly that these are for the programmer creating these pages, not a WebView trying to capture them? If so, then this is actually the opposite of what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry...misunderstood what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- website code -->

    <!-- The endless articles you want to process -->
    <div class="article">

    </div>
    <div class="article">

    </div>
    <div class="article">

    </div>
    <!-- ... -->        
</body>
</html>
```

Here would be the code to use:

```
(function($) {      // closure
    $(function() {  // when the document is ready
        var height      = $(this).height(), // get initial height
            lastEl      = null,                // track last element processed
            getData     =
                // this function will process the data as it comes in
                function() {
                    var $elements = $(".article");
                    // don't reprocess data
                    if(lastEl) { 
                        $elements = $elements
                            .slice($elements.index(lastEl)+1); 
                    }

                    lastEl = $elements
                        .each(function() {
                            // do what you want with the element
                        })
                        // save the last element processed
                        .get(-1) || lastEl; 

                    // finally, scroll to the bottom of the page
                    $(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
                };

        $(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
            var newHeight = $(this).height();
            if(newHeight != height) {
                height = newHeight;
                getData();
            }
        });
        getData();
    });
})(jQuery));
```

Just change the $elements selector to what you want to look for.  Then, you should be okay.  It is verbose, but also performance-light.

Comment: Looks promising, +1 for the nice "presentation".  Has anyone tried it?  I can't at the moment. :-(

Comment: Thank you.  I tested it locally, filling in a boatload of articles with Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless what language do you use, the solution is quite simple. You just catch the bechavior of user (by capturing current y and comparing it to max y od the page), then You have to add some new information to you content, by async connection. That is all.
Don't know very well Java so I can only give a hint, but the idea is the same in all technologies/languages.